# If demyelination doesn't typically occur, what happens when a musician doesn't practice for a month?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, learning, brain-training, training

In ["The Talent Code,"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00282MRU4) the author makes this statement:

> What's the simplest way to diminish the skills of a superstar talent? The answer: don't let them practice for a month. Causing skill to evaporate...only requires that you stop a skilled person from systematically firing his or her circuit [and continuing to grow myelin] for a mere thirty days.

However, later in the book there is this statement:

> Myelin wraps—it doesn't unwrap. Like a highway-paving machine, myelination happens in one direction. Once a skill circuit is insulated, you can't un-insulate it (except through age or disease).

*Assuming these are both true*, how do they coexist? If a neural circuit is not getting un-insulated in a month of no practice, why can't the performer resume at their previous level of skill?

Comment: Improvement with practice involves both forming new unmyelinated connections and myelinating existing connections. After a long period of not practicing a skill, both myelinated and unmyelinated connections may disappear. Myelinated connections are more stable than unmyelinated connections but they are not immutable.